# Inserting Values in to a self-referencing Table in SQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have created a table with this T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Mgrno VARCHAR(10),
    Empno VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    EmpName VARCHAR(50),
    Department VARCHAR(20),
    Email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(20),

    CONSTRAINT Employeefk 
        FOREIGN KEY (Mgrno) REFERENCES Employee 
);

INSERT INTO Employee (mgrno, empno, empname, department, email, phone)
VALUES ('B1205', 'A1206', 'deborah', 'Engineering', 'debs@aol.com', '234567);
```

But I am getting this error message - I need help - please...

> ERROR:  Key (mgrno)=(B1205) is not present in table "employee".insert or update on table "employee" violates foreign key constraint "employeefk"
>
> ERROR:  insert or update on table "employee" violates foreign key constraint "employeefk"
> SQL state: 23503
> Detail: Key (mgrno)=(B1205) is not present in table "employee".

I have deleted and recreated the table - but keep getting the same result

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is no employee `B1205` in the table, so you can't create a row that references it as a manager (the foreign key constraint prevents it). Insert the row of the manager first (with employee id `B1205`, and presumably a `null` manager id), then the employee row.

Comment: @FrankHeikens The foreign key is fine; it points to `empno`.

Comment: What is "T-SQL" supposed to mean? Are you confusing Postgres with SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can insert a row with a certain `mgrno`, you have to insert a row with that `empno`, otherwise the foreign key constraint would be violated.

So start with inserting a row where `mgrno` is NULL and `empno` is `'B1205'`.

Comment: Can you share the code...Thanks

Comment: `INSERT INTO Employee (mgrno, empno, empname, department, email, phone)
VALUES (NULL, 'B1205', 'laurenz', 'Management', 'lau@aol.com', '1');`